# Regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got an external text file which looks like this:

```
This_ART is_P an_ART example_N.
Thus_KONJ this_ART is_P a_ART part_N of_PREP it_N.
```

Now I want to open this file in Ruby and make an Array with every annotated word. My attempt looks like this:

```
def get_entries(file)
  return File.open(file).map { |x| x.split(/\W+_[A-Z]+/) }
end
```

but the execution just returns an Array with each sentence as a member:

```
[["This_ART is_P an_ART example_N.\n"],["Thus_KONJ this_ART is_P a_ART part_N of PREP it_N.\n"]]
```

The punctuation and the escape characters are included. Where is the mistake or what do I have to change to get the correct array?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you _want_ the matched output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try scanning for just the ones you want, e.g.

```
return File.read(file).scan(/\w+_[A-Z]+/)
```

that will give you something like:

```
["This_ART", "is_P", "an_ART", "example_N", "Thus_KONJ", ...]
```

if you want the annotation part removed, you could tack on:

```
.map{ |w| w.gsub(/_[A-Z]+\z/, '') }
```

note that \w is word chars and \W is non-word chars

Comment: Yes this did it, I actualy wasn't precise enough but I ment the first solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
/\W+_[A-Z]+/
```

matches only if there is a non-word character before the `_`, which isn't the case in your string.

I don't know exactly what you're expecting as a result, but try this:

```
/_[A-Z]+\W*/
```

Splitting along this regex gives you

```
["This", "is", "an", "example", "Thus", "this", "is", "a", "part", "of", "it"]
```